# Why I use matplotlib.pyplot(plt) lib to show some points but it cannot show line between the points

Tags: python, matplotlib, roc

There is a for-loop in my part of code, and every step it can generate new tpr(as X), fpr(as Y) like that

```
0.05263157894736842 0.1896551724137931
0.06578947368421052 0.19540229885057472
0.07894736842105263 0.22988505747126436
0.07894736842105263 0.25862068965517243
0.07894736842105263 0.28735632183908044
```

I want collect all these points and get a full plot, but it didn't work. And my code are attached below

```
for i in range (-30,20):
    predicted = (np.sign(t+i*1e-4)+1)/2.
    vals, cm = re.get_CM_vals(y_test, predicted)
    tpr = re.TPR_CM(cm)
    fpr = re.FPR_CM(cm)
    #print(tpr, fpr)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr,'b.-',linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Beside, I want to the the right angle line between points like that.is there a func in matplotlib?
[image]

Comment: use `plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'bo')` if you want to print points. Default plt.plot wants to draw lines but it can not with only one point. [Details here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

Comment: You could also use `plt.scatter(tpr, fpr)` for a scatter point plot. More importantly, to help us help you, we need more information about your problem instead of "but it didn't work". Did your code give you an error, or did it give you a result that doesn't visually match what you desire. If so, provide an example of what you get/what you want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current code, I suggest adding the x values to an array and the y values to another array. You could also use something like: `ArrayName = [[],[]]`, then append the x and y values to `ArrayName[0]` and `ArrayName[1]`, respectively. Not only would this actually work, but it would be slightly faster, since the `plt.plot` and `plt.scatter` functions work faster plotting all the points at once instead of through a for loop.

If you don't want to plot the points connected with lines, I still suggest using an array since that would be faster. (It wouldn't be that much faster in this case, but it's a good habit to have.